# vertical subseteq symbol in label of subfloat

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subfloats, labels, rotating

Math symbols (`\subseteq` and `\supseteq`) are rotated and rendered successfully in text mode with the aid of `\rotatebox{}{}`.

In the commented section below, there is a problem with getting these symbols into the subfloat label. I'm using `pdflatex`

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)`
 Any ideas? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox} 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, patterns}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{$\supseteq$}
\rotatebox{90}{$\subseteq$}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%\subfloat[Text $\overline{A\cup B}$,\;$\downarrow$\rotatebox{90}{$\supseteq$}]{
\subfloat[Text $\overline{A\cup B}$,\;$\downarrow$]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, auto, swap]
   \draw (-1,0) circle (1);
   \draw (2,0) circle (1);
   \node at (-2,1) [above left] {$A$};
   \node at (3,1) [above right] {$B$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}\qquad
\caption{Sets}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Addition of parameter `origin=c` to
`\subfloat[Text $\overline{A\cup B}$,\;$\downarrow$\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\subseteq$}]{` Without as seen in the picture.

[image]

Error while compiling `Runaway argument?
origin=c\caption@ifstrut {\ifhmode \@finalstrut \strutbox \fi }{}
! Paragraph ended before \Grot@box@kv was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.30 ...ownarrow$\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}
                                                  {$\subseteq$}]{`

Comment: What version of TeX/TikZ are you using? I seem to be getting an error on `tikzlibrary`.  `Latex Error: ./untitled2.tex:13 I can't find file \`tikzlibrary'.`  Is it just my distribution?

Comment: As far as I can tell my configuration is `latex2e`, `pdfTeX`, `pdflatex`, `Tex Live 2010`...for `tikz` I would say the latest available version :) My error is `! Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.30 }
      \qquad`

Comment: Oh, my, it seems I haven't run an update in a while, so I may be a bit outdated. I'll let you know what I find out when it finishes updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\protect` before `\rotatebox`. This prevents the early expansion of `\rotatebox`, see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) for an explanation.

```
\subfloat[Text $\overline{A\cup B}$,\;$\downarrow$\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\supseteq$}]{
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make `\subfloat[Text $\overline{A\cup B}$,\;$\downarrow$\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\subseteq$}]{` work? rotating `\subseteq` `-90` changes symbol height or moves it vertical lower.

Comment: @panny: it works if you define a macro: `\newcommand*{\rot}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\subseteq$}}` and protect that later in the subfloat command: `...\protect\rot`.